# SQL: Convert an integer into a hex string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, colors, hex

How do you convert an integer into a string of hex?
I want to convert the int into a format that I can use as a color on my page for example '#ff0000'.

So for example:

```
--This converts my int to hex:
CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), Color) Color,
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
'#' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), Color)) Color
```

But converting a varbinary string just converts it to an ascii character rather than returning the actual hex string

Comment: That seems to be for converting an int into a hex format like #0xFF4B0082. I need a string format that I can append a '#' to the start of like '#4B0082'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a built in function to generate hex *strings* from binary values

```
SELECT
    '#' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(BINARY(3), 0)),
    '#' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(BINARY(3), 255))
```

You need `binary(3)` to ensure the correct length of the output string
This is wrong. You get 4 hex digits because 0 and 255 here are 4 byte `int` values

```
SELECT
    '#' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(varBINARY(8), 0)),
    '#' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(varBINARY(8), 255))
```

Oct 2017 Update:

The conversion is now built-in to SQL Server (since 2008!!) so we can simply use CONVERT

```
SELECT '#' + CONVERT(char(6), CONVERT(BINARY(3), 2570841), 2)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I can't notice any difference between the two options here. In the end I used RIGHT( , 6) in order to trim the '0x' that these functions return a the start of the string and it worked! Thanks again x

Comment: The value returned by this function begins with `0x`, so you need `RIGHT (... , 6)` around `sys.fn_varbintohexstr` to make look as `#FF00FF`.

Comment: (Realizing this answer is over four years old --) Why not use [use `CONVERT`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1708816/Replacement-for-using-fnvarbintohexstr#bm1708994)? `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 987654321),2)`?

Comment: @ruffin: that syntax was only added in SQL Server 2008. Compare https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx vs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx "Binary Styles". OP was using SQL Server 2008, but I probably got mixed up in what version is which

Answer (score 2):

Conversion from int to varbinary is implicit in SQL SERVER, so you can also use
SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr(1234567) 
and you're done.

But beware BIGINT values, because long numeric literals are interpreted as DECIMAL values and not as BIGINT. Decimals have prefix data to hold the precision, and the byte order is reversed, and that's why you get this:

```
select sys.fn_varbintohexstr(2147483648)
```

returns 0x0A00000100000080

You need to convert explicitly to BIGINT:

```
select select sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(BIGINT(2147483648))
```

returns 0x0000000080000000